# Save request data or model to xml

Tags: xml, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'd like to save the request data or the model itself to an XML file. Can this be done out of the box?

```
$xml = Xml::build($this->request->data);
$file = new File('xml/test.txt', true);
$file->write($xml);
$file->close();
```

doesn't work. The file is empty.

```
$xml = Xml::build($this->MyModel);
```

Throws an exception.

Can this be done somehow out of the box?

Comment: Have you checked what `$xml` actually is? For sure [**it's not a string**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html#importing-data-to-xml-class)! Also what would you expect `Xml::build($this->MyModel)` to do?

Comment: It's an xml object. So it can be saved with $xml->saveXML('name.xml')? I'd like to get all post parameters with their values in the xml file like <parameter>value</parameter>.